# How soft photons carry away energy

Tags: particle-physics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

While studying the infrared traces, I came across the following Feynman diagram:

[image]

This diagram shows the braking radiation and the radiation correction of a soft photon. There are three vertices in the diagram, but there can be no odd interaction in QED. At the same time, soft photons really carry away energy.

Comment: can you give a link of where you found the diagram?.

Comment: What does “infrared races” mean?

Comment: What does muon pair production have to do with bremsstrahlung?

Comment: to get a bremsstrahlung photon  diagram an interaction with a field is needed.  https://www.sarthaks.com/454203/draw-feynman-diagrams-for-a-bremsstrahlung-b-pair-production

Comment: That is Feynman diagram describing the behavior and interaction of subatomic particles.

Comment: @Ghoster it might be traces not races